# GUI on runtime differs from Designed GUI on NetBeans GUI builder

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I am using `JTabbedpane` with a `JPanel` tabbed and all the components inside the panel are shown in the picture below:

This was, what I expected:

[image: This was, what I expected]

As given in below pic, the tabbed pane/panel is cropped, hence the buttons are not visible as designed in NetBeans.

This is, what I am getting:

[image: This is, what I am getting]

Even when the GUI windows is maximized, it is still cropped as shown in below pic

Still looks same after maximizing the windows.

[image: Still looks same after maximizing the windows]

There's no additional code, I've written in GUI source code. And yet I am facing the issue.

Comment: *"Ther's no additional code"* There's no code at all. For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: You need to add code that switches to the Windows Look and Feel.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Users of Mac OS and *nix would be horrified (if it were even possible to foist the Windows PLAF on them).

Comment: @AndrewThompson: the Mr Walkan should switch to the "system look and feel"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I just created the GUI (drag & drop) & ran, that's it. No written code inside the GUI source code.

Comment: @MrWalkan: the preview window in the GUI builder uses the current look & feel of the NetBeans IDE (in this case the Windows L&F). If you want to control which L&F is used at runtime, you will have to write some code. I think there should be something in the `main()` method that NetBeans generated that calls `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(...)` using the "cross platform L&F"

Comment: *"No written code inside the GUI source code."* So create an MRE / SSCCE (severely simplified, just put a label with an empty border for sizing in each tab and create them in a loop) and post *that* code that Netbeans produces. But without an MRE / SSCCE, I cannot help further.